# How to boost 12V DC to 24V DC?

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to power an ultrasonic mist module, which works at 24V and requires a few milliAmps. I have a 12V DC power supply, how can I use it to power my ultrasonic module?

I searched on the internet and there are multiple(rather complex for a beginner) ways given to do so, is there a simple way a beginner can get his way around it?

Comment: Buy a 24V power supply or build a boost converter?

Comment: This is quite off-topic but you can use premade boost module.

Comment: Just get a Xl 4015 DC-DC boost converter from ebay or amazon. They cost like only $7 to $13 bucks. Also get the one with both current and voltage pot. https://www.amazon.com/Converter-DROK-Buck-Boost-Adjustable-Regulator/dp/B0789QVKKF/ref=pd_day0_hl_504_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B0789QVKKF&pd_rd_r=45e46884-b420-11e8-bcdb-932140fb8169&pd_rd_w=r0G7G&pd_rd_wg=B8GSE&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=ad07871c-e646-4161-82c7-5ed0d4c85b07&pf_rd_r=4SPM9QM5E3JYX384V82M&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&refRID=4SPM9QM5E3JYX384V82M&th=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two basic methods are to use a crude voltage doubler, or a fairly simple boost switching regulator. If you cannot build one from scratch parts, a pre made module can be purchased on good electronic sourcing sites like Digikey, Farnell, etc, or less quality sites like eBay Amazon etc.

Or buy a 24V supply. A cheap wallwart can be found on the same sites, or a thrift shop.

Comment: Voltage doubler may be really good because there is only a few mA draw.  The problem with the doubler is the capacitor drains easily.